# How to use Gabor filter with Sobel and DFT filter outputs

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, filter

I'm going to employ Gabor filter on an image to enhance it, following the main idea of [this article](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~turkel/imagepapers/fingerprint.pdf) on image enhancement. The goal is to obtain orientation and frequency of the input image, then use them for Gabor filtering. 
First, I converted the image to grayscale, then for getting the orientation image, I used Sobel filter, and for frequency image, I used DFT filter. My codes are similar to the OpenCV documentation examples.

For Sobel:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html

and adding this part to the code in above link to get orientation image:

```
cv::Mat calculateOrientations(cv::Mat gradientX, cv::Mat gradientY)
{
    // Create container element
    cv::Mat orientation = cv::Mat(gradientX.rows, gradientX.cols, CV_32F);

    // Calculate orientations of gradients --> in degrees
    // Loop over all matrix values and calculate the accompagnied orientation
    for (int i = 0; i < gradientX.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < gradientX.cols; j++)
        {
            // Retrieve a single value
            float valueX = gradientX.at<float>(i, j);
            float valueY = gradientY.at<float>(i, j);
            // Calculate the corresponding single direction, done by applying the arctangens function
            float result = cv::fastAtan2(valueX, valueY);
            // Store in orientation matrix element
            orientation.at<float>(i, j) = result;
        }
    }   

    return orientation;
}
```

For DFT:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html

Then, I store the outputs of these two filters, and pass them as input params for my Gabor filter. The input image of my Gabor filter is a binary mask of my grayscale image. For this part, my code is as follows:

```
cv::Mat filter(cv::Mat inputImg, cv::Mat orientationImg, cv::Mat frequency, double theta_x, double theta_y)
{
    cv::Mat gaborResult = cv::Mat::zeros(inputImg.rows, inputImg.cols, inputImg.type());

    for (int i = 0; i < inputImg.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < inputImg.cols; j++)
        {
            float xTheta = i*cos(orientationImg.at<float>(i, j)) + j*sin(orientationImg.at<float>(i, j));
            float yTheta = -i*sin(orientationImg.at<float>(i, j)) + j*cos(orientationImg.at<float>(i, j));

            float num1 = (xTheta * xTheta) / (theta_x * theta_x);
            float num2 = (yTheta * yTheta) / (theta_y * theta_y);

            float res = exp((-1 / 2) * (num1 + num2)) * cos(2 * pi * frequency.at<float>(i, j) * xTheta);
            gaborResult.at<float>(i, j) = res;
        }
    } 

    cv::Mat result = mult(inputImg, gaborResult);
    return result;
}

cv::Mat mult(cv::Mat inputImage, cv::Mat gaborResult)
{

    cv::Mat enhancedImg = cv::Mat::zeros(inputImage.rows, inputImage.cols, inputImage.type());;
    float sum = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < inputImage.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < inputImage.cols; j++)
        {
            enhancedImg.at<float>(i, j) = gaborResult.at<float>(i, j) * inputImage.at<float>(i, j);
        }
    }

    return enhancedImg;
}
```

The params, `theta_x` and `theta_y` are 4.0, as the article suggests. The `orientationImg` and `frequency` come from Sobel and DFT operations respectively.
And I did a pixel-wise Gabor filtering as seen above. However, the output image is very strange, not even close to my enhancement goal.

This is the original input image to Sobel and DFT filters:

[image]

This is the input binary mask to Gabor filter:

[image]

This is the final output of my Gabor filter:

[image]

Obviously I'm not employing Gabor filter correctly here. I've searched a lot on the internet about this topic, but none of them solved my problem. Most of them emphasize on getting one Gabor kernel and use it on the entire image, which is different in my case. Can someone has a better idea about improving my code/finding out my errors? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like unnormalized float output.
Try to normalize it to interval [0,1].

```
cv::normalize(src,dst,0,1,cv::NORM_MINMAX);
```

Comment: I've already tried that method, but it didn't solve my problem.